# Comparison of yield and static local variable

Tags: c#, c++, c

While reading up on the yield keyword in C# it struck me that it seems there is some similarity with the use of a static variable declared inside a function such as can be done in C.

Both are methods of saving the state of a function between calls without exposing this fact outside the function.

First question: what are the differences between the two in terms of how they save the function's state?

Second question: what are the design implications saving a function's state opaquely like this? I have seen some "hacks" based on yield which seem like a disaster waiting to happen. Are there any situations besides enumerable collections that actually benefit from this design?

Comment: I will suggest think about one language at a time.

Comment: I would say the similarities you see are stretching it.

Comment: @Grijesh I'm looking to compare C# with C. C++ by virtue of being a superset of C is also relevant to the comparison.

Comment: C++ is not a superset of C.

Comment: @Martinho the similarity is not far off. Consider a function with a static local variable in C which returns localvar++ versus a C# which has a for loop that yield returns the value of i

Comment: Ok it's not a exactly a superset. For the purpose of the question it behaves the same

Comment: If your iterator is just a function, with a small local state, it's cleaner to implement it as in C++, as an object.  If iterating involves visiting complex data structures, using recursion, then it's cleaner to use `yield`, since otherwise, you have to manage the stack by hand.

Comment: I fail to see what part of this question deserves a down vote, it would be helpful if the vote was accompanied by a reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# `yield` looks very much like the `yield` in Python.  If
so, it's closer to a co-process than to a static variable: the
entire state of the function is saved.  (Back in the old days,
the way we implemented co-processes on an Intel was to exchange
the stack pointer with a memory location: `xchg sp,
otherCoprocessStack`.)

As for the advantages, it's a lot more light weight than
defining a separate thread, and communicating with it via some
sort of queuing mechanism.  It's particularly useful when
iterating over complex memory structures, like trees, since it
avoids having to maintain a stack manually.